# SetOwningMol RDKIT in python3

Tags: python-3.x, rdkit

I have a couple of function definitions in a wider class that I'm writing in python. For one function I embed the molecules with n number of conformers, I then want to make sure that these conformers remain with the parsed molecule after the function call. I thought this was done by reference under the hood so I wouldn't have to specifically set the conformers (see code snippet 1. below). However, this doesn't see to be the case. I tried to parse back the conformers and then do a setOwningMol but I get an error saying that the conformer class has no attribute setOwningMol or SetOwningMol (see snippet 2.) Any ideas on how to proceed would be great.

snippet 1:

```
gen_conformers(rdkitmol,n)
rdkmol.GetNumConformers() #### returns 0 here, I thought this would be done by reference?

def gen_conformers(rdkitmol,n):
    cids = AllChem.EmbedMultipleConfs(rdkmol,numConfs=n)
    rdkmol.GetNumConformers() #### returns n here
```

snippet 2:

```
confs = gen_conformers(rdkitmol,n)
for conf in confs:
    conf.SetOwningMol(rdkitmol)  #### 'Conformer' object has no attribute 'SetOwningMol' I tried with setOwningMol also

def gen_conformers(rdkitmol,n):
    cids = AllChem.EmbedMultipleConfs(rdkmol,numConfs=n)
    return rdkmol.GetConformers()
```

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is here. When I run your code the conformers are embedded within the molecule object. Although I noticed that your function takes `rdkitmol` as an argument whereas in the function body you use `rdkmol`. I think this may be the problem here

Comment: Thank you for looking at this issue.  Indeed checking this myself it does work this way (spelling errors aside).  The code above is just a "reproduction" from the wider code. I had a slight difference in that the rdkit molecule getting parsed to the function was an attribute of another class accessed via a @property, I believe this is the root cause.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, I don't think this should be an issue unless you are passing copies of the molecule to the function. Maybe you could share a reduced portion of the class you are working with? Also to add a conformer to a molecule it should be done the other way around like: `mol.AddConformer(conformer)`

Comment: Yes there was a copy issue I've resolved it now thank you for your help. This was a reply I got on got github for the issue on the SetOwningMol question, which as you rightly suggest is "AddConformer"  >>> help(mol.AddConformer)
Help on method AddConformer:

AddConformer(...) method of rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol instance
    AddConformer( (Mol)self, (Conformer)conf [, (bool)assignId=False]) -> int :
        Add a conformer to the molecule and return the conformer ID
    
        C++ signature :
            unsigned int AddConformer(RDKit::ROMol {lvalue},RDKit::Conformer* [,bool=False])